# Auto-scale: run everywhere or on-demand?

Tags: scalability, akka.net

I am involved in developing of a set of microservices with distributed processing capabilities with the help of Akka.NET.

Typically they consist of some dispatcher and some workers. Dispatcher by default assign work to his local worker, but when it [somehow] determines that current host is overloaded then assigns work to remote workers.

Say we have 10 hosts (VMs) and 30 such services (semantically different).

*The question is: how to properly scale them?*
The first solution is to run 3-services-per-host with capability to auto-scale each service on-demand on other 9 machines. And scale-down when not needed after some time. 
The second solution is to run all 30 services on all 10 hosts always.

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, you need to consider fault tolerance, localisation, recovery, general distributed computing issues such as CAP etc..

Unless you have different scaling needs for different services, I'd probably go for the second approach of running them on all hosts. This gives greater fault tolerance and seems conceptually simpler than having auto-scaling. However, this presumes you have similar needs for each type of service and means all services will be affect by an outage or failure of a host. If one particular service has different needs (I.e. Different SLA, non functional requirements, more powerful machine needed etc.) then there is more of an argument for more specialised deployments per service.